# How to convert a string of bytes and a format to Audio in C# Xamamrin

Tags: c#, xamarin

In the JSON response,

```
{
"audio_bytes": "IyFBTVIKPHxLb+hMacfM6meP90JAdIAAF/pDsVUEAABYEqAuNSA8bkx7OIxeEt4EfZiQe0I1Lq2kpvlW3ObkpIHTZRLg4Dx6SyTq5i4BvhEfCeXMpyzhiepROrvDsHoTTqUMhFTgPDhEmjhnvRP+EYFasegtHr2CR9eZnU/liW6ghERhETA8ek",
"audio_format": "wav"
}
```

(1) How can I restore this string of bytes to an audio File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
File.WriteAllBytes("Message1.wav", bytes);
```

First convert back from string to the bytes array since its Base64 string.
Then file it to a file with the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("yourfilepath.wav", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(somestring));
```